# Deploying Mask RCNN in a web application

Tags: rest, api, tensorflow, computer-vision, object-detection

- Can anybody help me with how to deploy the Mask-RCNN model in a web application?
- I want to upload an image and display the segmented image back on the web page. But I'm not sure of how to deploy the neural network in the web application. Please help.[here the notebook](http://colab.research.google.com/github/zaidalyafeai/Notebooks/blob/master/Mask_RCNN.ipynb#scrollTo=YBaILxtBPyBu&uniqifier=2)

Comment: have you found any solution?

Comment: I still haven't figured out. As soon as I find a way, I'll let you know...if u figure out a way too, please let me know

Comment: Please follow this 3 part tutorial series: https://blog.keras.io/building-a-simple-keras-deep-learning-rest-api.html. It works for me.

Comment: - GitHub repo--> https://github.com/Boyetuhin/MasRcnn-WebApp 
- I only have the working Flask app on my localhost , where if you run it on a local host , you can upload video/picture....But to get the result (removed video background) I've to integrate the G-colab model into this Flask ri8? //Which is what I'm wondering.